# Difference between Rajasthani "sev tamatar nu shak" and Gujrati "sev tamatar nu shak"

Tags: indian-cuisine

What is the difference between Rajasthani "sev tamatar nu shak" and Gujrati "sev tamatar nu shak". Do they use different spices or ingredients or method of cooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rajasthani is typically spicier (red and green chillies), and/or sour with green tomatoes

Gujarati is typically sweeter (Look for jaggery in recipe)

Otherwise it's a very generic Indian reciepe

Comment: hmmm there is no onion in either of them I think